# How can i print the specific line number of a json file

Tags: python, json, loops, jsonschema

I am using `python` to load a json file and using `jsonschema` to print errors according to the `schema` i have prepared.

**My question is how do i print a specific line of a json file** from a loop:

```
errors = sorted(validator.iter_errors(jsonData[a]), key=lambda e: e.path)
for error in errors:
    print(error.message, sep=", ")
```

The output i get is `'lending_details' is a required property` which is the `error.message`.

**What i want is to print: `On line number 4 ,'lending_details' is a required property`**

**Is there a way to count and display the specific line number of a json file?**

Comment: Try using enumerate? Like this `for index, error in enumerate(errors):`

Comment: Thanks for that but it just loops starting from 0, displaying `Exception on line number 0 : 'lending_details' is a required property` and if there is another error the index displays 1, i want to display line number of json file which should display: `Exception on line number 15 : 'lending_details' is a required property`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, no, because by the time the JSON Schema evaluator sees the data instance, the data has been parsed from JSON text into a data structure and the line number information has been lost.

To make this work, you will need to have a JSON decoder that can associate line numbers with each section of the data in a way that the JSON Schema evaluator can later make use of it when generating its errors.  For example, I could see a decoder turning this JSON:

```json
{
  "foo": {
    "hello": [
      "a",
      "b",
      "c"
    ]
  "bar": true
}
```

into this line number mapper:

```
{
  "": 1,
  "/foo": 2,
  "/foo/hello": 3,
  "/foo/hello/0": 4,
  "/foo/hello/1": 5,
  "/foo/hello/2": 6,
  "/bar": 8
}
```

..and then when the JSON Schema evaluator is generating an error at data instance "/bar", we can use this lookup table to insert "..at line 8" into the error.

Comment: Yes this will work, but suppose i have a file which contains few required fields in a json and that the JSON Schema evaluator checks other fields which are not required and not present in the json file will take up the count in the decoder file and hence i will get  a wrong line number. Thanks for the idea though!

Comment: Well of course data that is missing can't have a line number, so that will need to be accomodated in the error message somehow. :p

Comment: Thanks though i completed the project :D! I am now just displaying the path where the json is having a validation error.